# Obtain a data.frame (or list) of X times the the original source, after applying some function

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply

I've been having problems with this one for a while.

What I would like, is to apply a function to a data.frame that is divided by factors. This data frame has n>2 columns of values that I need to use for this function.

For the sake of this example, this dataset has a column of 5 factors (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`), and 2 columns of values (`values1`,`values2`). I would like to apply a number of functions that takes into account each column of values (`auto.arima` first and `forecast.Arima`, in this case). A dataset to play follows:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(factors = letters[1:5],values1 = rnorm(50), values2 =rnorm(50))
```

This previous dataset has a column of 5 factors (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`), and 2 columns of values (`values1`,`values2`). I would like (for the sake of the exercise), to apply auto.arima to values1 and values 2, per factor. My expected output would be *something* that, per factor, takes into account both columns of values, and forecasts both (each as its own univariate time series). So if the dataset has 5 factors and 2 columns of values, I would need 10 lists/data.frames.

Some options that did not work: Splitting the data.frame per factor via:

```
split(dat, dat$factor)
```

And then using `rapply`:

```
rapply(dat,function(x) forecas.Arima(auto.arima(x)),dat$factors)
```

Or `lapply`:

```
lapply(split(dat,dat$factors), function(x) forecast.Arima(auto.arima(x)))
```

And some other combinations, all to no avail.

I thought that the easiest solution would involve a function in the apply family, but any solution would be valid.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is what're you asking, but you could `melt` the `data.frame` with `"factors"` as the `id.vars`, split on `"factors"` and the `variable` column you'll get from the `melt`, then `lapply` your function on the resulting list.

Comment: by the way on your example what is the univariate time series on whic you wanna apply `auto.arima`? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel in this example, I'd like to apply auto.arima to values1 and values2, per factor

Comment: so you wanna apply for factor 'a' auto.arima on the 10 values of value1 and the 10 values of value2?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Yes, exactly, and the same procedure for b,c,d and e.

Comment: @erasmortg: in your `lapply` function you are passing the whole dataframe to `auto.arima`. I believe that you just want to pass `x$values1` or `x$values2` and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
m = melt(dat, id.vars = "factors")
l = split(m, paste(m$factors, m$variable))
lapply(l, function(x) forecast.Arima(auto.arima(x$value)))
```

i.e. splitting the data into 10 different frames, then applying the forecast on the `values`?

Comment: I would use plyr as an alternative: `ldply(unique(m[,c('factors', 'variable')]), function(x) ...)` but +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you `apply` solutions is that you were passing the whole dataframe to the `auto.arima` function which take a vector so you'd need something like this:

```
lapply(split(dat,dat$factors), function(df) {
    apply(df[,-1], 2, function(col) forecast.Arima(auto.arima(col)))
})
```

This splits the dataframe as before on the factors and then applies over each column (ignoring the first which is the factor) the `auto.arima` function wrapped in `forecast.Arima`. This returns a list of lists (5 factors by 2 values) so allows you to keep `values1` and `values2` separate.

You can use `unlist(x, recursive=FALSE)` to flatten this to a list of 10.

Comment: Thank you for the extra answer. However, when I try to use them as is, the first one throws an error, while the second one forecasts -1 for every point, and it also gives only 5 forecasts, instead of 10 (2 per factor).